# Adjust the font size of a node in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to set the font size of the `node` in the following code to `\small` ? I want to have the font size of the `node` to be the same as the font size specified under `LM/.style`. I tried `\node at (0.9,0.85) {\small $\phi$};`. This does not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,quotes}
\tikzset{
LM/.style = {very thin,
        {Bar[]Stealth}-%
        {Stealth[]Bar}
            },
every edge quotes/.append style= {font=\footnotesize},
  every node/.append style ={font=\small} 
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp!]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [LM] (1,0.6) to ["$\phi = 45$"] (2,0.6);
\node at (0.9,0.85) {\small $\phi$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\node[font=\small]`, but the question is unclear to me:

- Style `LM` does not specify any font size.
- `every node/.append style={font=\small}` is using `\small`, but this is not
  used in `"$\phi = 45$"`, it uses `\footnotesize` by the setting of `every node edge quotes/.append style={font=\footnotesize}`.

  Maybe, `\node[font=\footnotesize]` is what you want.

Comment: BTW, if `\phi` denotes an angle, then the degree symbol is very likely missing after the number `45`.

Comment: `$\phi=\qty{45}{\degree}$` with `siunitx`, and you can enjoy the correct spacing... 

Answer (score 5):

The `\small` in the node text will override the `\footnotesize` of the `font` key, which is activated *before* starting to typeset the node, as said by Heiko Oberdiek. Notice that font-size commands are absolute in LaTeX --- `\small` does not mean *smaller*...

To show what happens:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz, siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,quotes}
\tikzset{
LM/.style = {very thin,
        {Bar[]Stealth}-%
        {Stealth[]Bar}
            },
every edge quotes/.append style= {font=\footnotesize},
  every node/.append style ={font=\small} 
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp!]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [LM] (1,0.6) to ["$\phi = 45$"] (2,0.6);
\node at (0.9,0.85) {\small $\phi$};
\begin{scope}[yshift=-1cm, blue]
    \draw [LM] (1,0.6) to ["$\phi = \qty{45}{\degree}$"] (2,0.6);
    \node at (0.8,0.85) {\footnotesize $\phi$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]